# Python: Parse table with missing tab at end

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

Is there a way to use pandas read table or read fwf to parse a text file that has empty fields and the tabbed delimiter stops if there aren't any more fields in the line. Example: I added spaces to be readable but they aren't there between tabs. There should be 5 columns A:E

```
A \t B \t C \t D \t E            \r\n
word 1 \t 1 \t 2  \t text  \t s  \r\n
       \t 0 \t 20                \r\n
word 2 \t 1 \t 5                 \r\n
       \t   \t    \t text2       \r\n
word 6 \t 2 \t 6  \t text3 \t s  \r\n
```

I want NaN values or anything that says it's empty where there are empty fields. I've looked around for something like this and haven't found anything. I've also tried everything I can think of using pandas. I've thought about adding \t values to each line missing 4 but I was hoping there is an easier way since there are more issues with this data set besides just this. These data tables are separated by text in between because it is a pdf converted to text.

Expected Result:

```
   A      B    C     D      E
word 1    1    2    text    s
  NaN     0    20   NaN    NaN
word 2    1    5    NaN    NaN
  NaN    NaN  NaN  text2   NaN
word 6    2    6   text3    s
```

using

```
data = pd.read_fwf(filename, skiprows=range(0,10),skipfooter=8,sep='\t',na_values='NaN')
```

Comment: What you've tried ? And can you add an expected result ?

Comment: I've tried using read_table and read_fwf going with many different parameters from looking around online. Nothing seems to work. Everything gets put in the first column as a string. It doesn't parse the tab. I assume thats because theirs not a consistent number of tabs

Comment: also adding delim_whitespace=True retains the tabs inside the first column but doesn't separate them.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, after filtering out spaces from your example, it gets:

```
'A\tB\tC\tD\tE\r\nword 1\t1\t2\ttext\ts\r\n\t0\t20\r\nword 2\t1\t5\r\n\t\t\ttext2\r\nword 6\t2\t6\ttext3\ts\r\n'
```

which displays as (with tabs converted to spaces for every 8-th position):

```
A       B       C       D       E
word 1  1       2       text    s
        0       20
word 2  1       5
                        text2
word 6  2       6       text3   s
```

Pandas 0.23.4 reads it smoothly with (`na_values=''` asks to convert empty fields to `NaN`):

```
data = pandas.read_csv(file, sep='\t', na_values='')
print(data)
```

gives as expected:

```
        A    B     C      D    E
0  word 1  1.0   2.0   text    s
1     NaN  0.0  20.0    NaN  NaN
2  word 2  1.0   5.0    NaN  NaN
3     NaN  NaN   NaN  text2  NaN
4  word 6  2.0   6.0  text3    s
```